# How do I get the JWT tokens from user in Django RestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-request

I have a DRF project using Simple-JWT for authentication. When a user logs in, they get a response containing the access and refresh tokens in the `serializer.data`. However:

When testing on the Apis I can manually copy and paste these tokens and add them to headers when making requests. However in production,

1. Where are these tokens stored on the user's side?
2. How will the user be able to add the `access` token to requests that are protected? (they can't copy-paste like me)
3. How will they use the `refresh` token to renew the `access` token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you're talking about the client side, where users will be using your application using the front-end:

1. The tokens can be stored on **local storage** of your browser
2. All the authenticated URL requests must contain a **bearer** token where you will add the `access_token` which your API will return after authentication and is currently saved in your local storage.
3. for getting **refresh token**, add a URL like below where you will send a **post** request:

   ```
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
        TokenObtainPairView,
        TokenRefreshView,
        TokenVerifyView,
    )
    urlpatterns = [
    ...

        path(
            'token/refresh/',
            TokenRefreshView.as_view(),
            name='token_refresh',
        ),
    ...
    ]
   ```

**Finally** someone can use this code on JS side for saving or retrieving tokens from `localstorage`:

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Comment: Do I have to write code for storing and getting the tokens from the local storage?

Comment: of course, there's js code for saving and retrieving that data. You can search for that on stackoverflow

Comment: I think that's what I am looking for in this question (hence the question title).. I could not find it on stackoverflow

Comment: I believe I have answered your posted question to some extent. If possible please don't forget to upvote to let people know whether it was useful or not. 
And for your final question that you have mentioned, you can find the process here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage-sessionstorage

Comment: Yeah ..Now I can say all my questions are answered. Would you consider moving the final answer in the comments to your answer? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, please let me know which part would be helpful! Should I add the local storage data saving related code there?

Comment: Yes. The saving and retrieving code would be helpful

Comment: Got you, I'm adding that :)